# how to add text below two div tags

Tags: html, tags, frame

I have two div tags - current page appears like

```
-------------
<tag-1>   <tag-2>
---------------
```

now  I want to add some static text below these two div tags how to do that?
result page should look like -

```
--------------
<tag-1>  <tag-2>
some text with scroll bar
some text again
----------
```

current html

```
<body>
    <div id="tag1"></div>
    <div id="tag2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Perfectly clear question, correctly formatted code...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Html tip should resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both divs have a float: left; css tag to allow them to be side by side, you'd add another div with clear: both; css tag to make sure this contianer is below the float elements.

```
<body>    
<div style="float: left;" id="tag1">tag 1</div>    
<div style="float: left;" id="tag2">tag 2</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
My Text
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do this from javascript.  If so use [jQuery's after function](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

```
$('#tag2').after('some text')
```